# Optimize query to YouTube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Help optimize YouTube API requests. The entire quota is spent in 5 minutes

Get id TOP 5 trends:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&key={token}&fields=items(id)&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=RU&maxResults=5
```

Get channel id and channel name from video id:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={VideoId}&key={token}
```

Get channel name from username

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key={token}&forUsername={UserName}&part=id
```

Get channel image:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id={ChannelId}&part=snippet&key={token}
```

Video count on channel:

```
​https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?playlistId={ChannelId}&key={token}&part=snippet
```

Last video on channel:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={token}&channelId={ChannelId}&part=id&order=date&maxResults=1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I need to get data from YouTube, but to get requests to spend less quota points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are a few tips I think it might help:

1. Set specific fields to retrieve in each request.
2. The "search" request is the one who consumes more quota than the rest of your requests.

Here are your modified requests:

Get id TOP 5 trends - [Demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular&hl=RU&maxResults=5&fields=items%252Fid&_h=1&):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular&hl=<REGION_CODE>&maxResults=5&fields=items%2Fid&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Get channel id and channel name from video id: - [demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&id=JPJjwHAIny4&fields=items(snippet(channelId%252CchannelTitle))&_h=2&)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=<VIDEO_ID>&fields=items(snippet(channelId%2CchannelTitle))&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Get channel name from username *(also bring at the same time the channel image and its count of uploaded videos)* - [demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet%252Cstatistics&forUsername=TedtalksDirector&fields=items(snippet(thumbnails%252Ctitle)%252Cstatistics%252FvideoCount)&_h=7&)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2Cstatistics&forUsername=<CHANNEL_USERNAME>&fields=items(snippet(thumbnails%2Ctitle)%2Cstatistics%2FvideoCount)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Last video on channel: - [demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=contentDetails&playlistId=UUT2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g&fields=items(contentDetails(videoId%252CvideoPublishedAt))&_h=9&)

Here you can use other approach:

- Use the `channel_id` and replace the value as follows:

> Channel: Microsoft Hololens:
>
> Channel_id: U**C**T2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g
>
> Uploads *(playlist)*: U**U**T2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g

Once you get the *uploads (playlist)*, use the following request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=contentDetails&playlistId=<UPLOAD_PLAYLIST>&fields=items(contentDetails(videoId%2CvideoPublishedAt))&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And use the latest `videoId` from the response - *(which has the most recent updated time)*.