# Get video likes count according to region in youtube api

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I am using youtube api v3 for research purpose and i can get likes, dislikes, comments and more statistics but i want to get likes and views count according to region or country base. e-g i want to know how many likes and views any particular videos get from different region. Is this option is available in youtube_api v3.

```
def get_channel_videos(channel_id):
 res = youtube.channels().list(id=channel_id, 

 part='contentDetails').execute()
 playlist_id = res['items'][0]['contentDetails'] 
                             ['relatedPlaylists']['uploads']

 videos = []
 next_page_token = None
 while True:
    res = youtube.playlistItems().list(playlistId=playlist_id, 
                                       part='snippet', 
                                       maxResults=50, 
                          pageToken=next_page_token).execute()
     videos += res['items']
     next_page_token = res.get('nextPageToken')
     if next_page_token is None:
        break
  return videos

videos = get_channel_videos('UCqRTj-Nu_8to3jIBlXptOtA')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think youtube api doesnot give this feature but you can get trending videos list for any country. Please if any one has better suggestion let us know.

```
     youtube.videos().list(part='snippet, recordingDetails, statistics',
                           regionCode='US', chart='mostPopular', maxResults=50)
```

Comment: With the results of the request you're doing, make another request for videos for get the details of the videos returned. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54888861/12511801) for more details.